# Running a query over http using servicestack ormlite

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I have an app running in the browser.  The client is fetching data from the server using .net core WEBAPI. normal REST requests. Something like a criteria parser...

I wonder if there is a way to pass search criteria from the client to the server in order to query the database. converting a get request to a ormlite query is possible but I wonder if it's already done... 
I'm talking about serverside implementation, paging, sorting, searching (and,or) and so on...

I have a license for ormlite only.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds almost exactly like what [ServiceStack's AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) already does, where it's able to implement the Query Service for your RDBMS Table from just a Request DTO definition, e.g:

```
[Route("/movies")]
public class FindMovies : QueryDb<Movie>
{
    public string[] Ratings { get; set; }
}
```

Where you will then be able to call your Service with either a Typed Service Client:

```
var movies = client.Get(new FindMovies { Ratings = new[]{"G","PG-13"} })
```

Or via a HTTP request:

```
/movies?ratings=G,PG-13
```